# How to convert rows to columns by transforming and then repeating the next row?

Tags: oracle11g

Table contains the following columns and data:

```
Id | Date

1  | 04/09/2014 13:00:00
1  | 04/10/2014 15:00:00
1  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00
1  | 04/13/2014 18:00:00
2  | 04/11/2014 13:00:00
2  | 04/12/2014 15:00:00
2  | 04/12/2014 16:00:00
```

I need to get every vertical pair for each Id and transform it into horizontal view, the result should look like:

```
| ID |                   DATE1 |                   DATE2 |
|  1 | April, 09 2014 13:00:00 | April, 10 2014 15:00:00 |
|  1 | April, 10 2014 15:00:00 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00 |
|  1 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00 | April, 13 2014 18:00:00 |
|  1 | April, 13 2014 18:00:00 |                  (null) |
|  2 | April, 11 2014 13:00:00 | April, 12 2014 15:00:00 |
|  2 | April, 12 2014 15:00:00 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00 |
|  2 | April, 12 2014 16:00:00 |                  (null) |
```

Comment: I have solution for sql server and tried to convert it for oracle, but couldn't

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, date date1, (select date 
                        from data_table t2 
                        where t2.ROWID>t1.ROWID and t2.date>t1.date and ROWNUM=1) date2
from data_table t1
```

I'm not an Oracle guy, there might be error in given solution and also you will need to format your `DATE` fields according to your need.

Comment: Thank you, this solution doesn't work as expected, it skips some dates .

Comment: can you please paste output at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), as I don't have installed oracle here :)

Comment: I don't have required reputation in order to answer on my on question by showing result :(

Comment: I'm not asking for posting an answer dude. You just paste output in pastebin and give me link, so that I can inspect what is problem with my query.

Comment: this won't work `t2.id=t1.id`, because it will make inner join between `t1` and `t2`. From your expected output what I understood is, you want to mearge row with `next` row of the table right? for that purpose I had compared `t2.ROWID>t1.ROWID`

Comment: There was a small mistake in my query, i misspelled `t2.ROWID>t2.ROWID`, now changed to `t2.ROWID>t1.ROWID` try and let me know

Comment: I meant there is no problem  with syntax of query, the problem is result. Since inner query is not ordered and there is no index in a table, date from inner query returns unordered

Comment: Yes, it was a small mistake which has been changed by me and as I said there is no syntax error, the result is not the same as was expected and described

Comment: Do you have any other unique/primary column in table? If it is there then it would solve problem easily

Comment: I don't have any indexes primary/unique unfortunately

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: I've no idea, FAIK ROWID should work correctly if order of inserting rows is same as date, moreover you can add primary key column.